# Let $(A, \prec)$ be a totally ordered infinite set $\Rightarrow$ $A$ doesn't have a greatest element

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

In contradiction to the title, I have came up with the following counter-examples that contradicts the statement:

1. $(\Bbb N, \prec)$ such as $\prec = <$ In this case 0 is the greatest member.
2. $(\Bbb Z\setminus \Bbb N, \prec)$ such as $\prec = >$ In this case -1 is the greatest member.

Is there a more generic approach to provide contradiction to such statement instead of providing counter-example, perhaps by induction?

Comment: I am not sure what generic approach you mean, but your counter-examples are just enough to show the statement is false.

Comment: @JingeonAn I am not sure either, that's why I asked. It seems to me that more generic proofs could be written to contradict such statements.

Comment: No, I'd say there is no more generic approach to disproving this statement than giving a counterexample. Note that the statement you want to disprove is: $\forall A((A,<)\text{ is totally ordered infinite set}\Rightarrow A\text{ doesn't have the greatest element})$, so it is equivalent to say, you want to prove that $\exists A \lnot(\sim)$, which is done by giving a counterexample.

Comment: @JingeonAn Got it thanks